# How can I set a static location for a tabulator popup and its container

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator to display a table and clicking on the row displays a popup. The popup appears next to where the mouse is, but will sometimes break the popup window if the contents are too large. Occasionally the popup will display on the top left of the table and just have most of the content hidden. Even using `popupContainer:true` will cause this behavior.

I am looking for a way to have the popup have a static location a few pixels to the right of where the click event happened. That way it will always display to the right. I can change the position of the `tabulator-popup` element, but it will not be inside the `tabulator-popup-container`. If I change both elements, the dropdowns used in the header filters become offset as well.

Is there a way to adjust the position of both `tabulator-popup` and `tabulator-popup-container` without having to create a separate module or class for header filters and row click popups?